# Couchdb: Browser Access to list records

Tags: couchdb

I have just realised, all the `curl` commands being mentioned are able to be executed in the browser.

I can not seem to work out what is the correct command to get the output from a view.

My database is on iriscouch.

```
http://mysite.iriscouch.com/mydb/_design/myview
```

lists the view, but how do I run the view so that the records are displayed ?

Thanks - mcl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to insert `_view` into the url:

```
http://mysite.iriscouch.com/mydb/_design/mydesign/_view/myview
```